# Laravel sort help (multiple rules)

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I've got a sorting function that's been working great. Sorting a collection into a specific order based on attributes. Now however I've been asked to have it also (as much as possible) order things alphabetically also.

I have 2 static arrays which provide the order of the 2 current attributes. Currently this orders the collection by section, and then within section by season.

What I want to add is the items grouped by season are then ordered alphabetically. If that makes sense.

```
$mp = $mp->sort(function ($a, $b) use ($order, $subOrder) {

        $pos_a = array_search($a->section, $order);

        $pos_b = array_search($b->section, $order);

        if ($pos_a != $pos_b) {
            return $pos_a - $pos_b;
        }

        $pos_a2 = array_search($a->season, $subOrder);

        $pos_b2 = array_search($b->season, $subOrder);

        if ($pos_a2 != $pos_b2) {
            return $pos_a2 - $pos_b2;
        }

        return 0;

    });
```

In short of writing a static A->Z array and adding that array_search to the sort I'm struggling of finding a nice way of doing this. I tried simply ordering the original query, but my current sort function seems to disrespect the alphabetical query.

Really appreciate any push in the right direction!

Cheers